# Change the date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, c#

After picking a date from the date_delivery, the warranty end will automatically generate a date according to what is being set or added year to it.

This is my view:

```
       <th class="editor-label-dtp">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sw_delivery_date,"Delivery Date : ")
        </th>
        <td class="editor-field">
            <input type="text" id="date_delivered" name="sw_delivery_date" onchange="switchWarranty(this.value)">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sw_delivery_date)
        </td>
         <th class="editor-label-dtp">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sw_warranty_end,"Warranty End : ")
        </th>
        <td class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("warranty_end")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sw_warranty_end)
        </td>
```

My javascript code:

```
function switchWarranty(value) {

var setDate = new Date(value);
var setMonth = setDate.getMonth();
var totalMonth = setMonth + 36;
var computeYear = setDate.getYear() + parseInt(totalMonth / 12);
var computeMonth = totalMonth % 12;

var formatDate = computeMonth + 1 + '/' + (setDate.getDate() + 1) + '/' + computeYear;

document.getElementById("warranty_end").value = formatDate;
$('#warranty_end').datepicker({
    defaultDate: formatDate
});
```

}

When I tried to run this code in IE 11 browser, the date being generated in the warranty_end field is not as what I expected. The year becomes 118. Like if a pick the date of 05/25/2015 for delivery_date, the warranty end that is generated is 5/26/118. I am expecting an output of 05/25/2018. Please me with this one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the format of "value" is it in this format 13/01/2015 ie (dd/MM/yyyy) format?

Comment: so MM/dd/yyyy format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string in m/d/y format and wish to turn it into a Date that is 3 years hence, then you should first parse the string to a Date, then add 3 years to it (or 36 months if you prefer):

```
function parseMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[0]-1, b[1]);
}
```

And *switchWarranty* becomes:

```
function switchWarranty(value) {

  // Helper to add leading zero
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0':'') + n;}

  // Convert value to Date
  var date = parseMDY(value);

  // Add 36 months
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 36);

  // Create a formatted string
  var formatDate = z(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
                   z(date.getDate()) + '/' +
                   date.getFullYear();

  // Assume this bit works
  document.getElementById("warranty_end").value = formatDate;
  $('#warranty_end').datepicker({defaultDate: formatDate});
}
```

In the above, 29 February, 2016 plus 3 years becomes 1 March, 2019.

Note that you should never pass a string to the Date constructor. Built–in parsing of strings is very unreliable, e.g.

```
new Date('05/25/2015'))
```

in Safari returns *Invalid Date*.

Answer (score 1):

use getFullYear() instead of getYear() then you will get 2018 instead of 118.
try this

```
 var setDate = new Date("05/25/2015");
 var setMonth = setDate.getMonth();
 var totalMonth = setMonth + 36;
 var computeYear = setDate.getFullYear() + parseInt(totalMonth / 12);
 var computeMonth = totalMonth % 12;
 var day = (setDate.getDate() + 1).toString();
 var month = (computeMonth + 1).toString();
 month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
var formatDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + computeYear;
```

Comment: IE 11 will prompt an error `Unhandled exception at line 59, column 5 in eval code

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'val'`

Comment: @Jen143Me sorry .Val() can only use with id of the object..check my edited answer..there im calling `"#date_delivered"` value directly using the id

Comment: Wed May 09 201545 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time) - that is the output

Comment: Can I have this output 05/25/2015 ?